# Error when vibrating

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm trying to let a phone vibrate using phonegap with [cordova-plugin-vibration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-vibration/) plugin. I have code that works on android phones but when I try it with an ios device it doesn't work, I can't let it vibrate.

My JS:

```
function vibrate() {
    var time = 3000;
    navigator.vibrate(time);
    alert('vibrate for 3 seconds');
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><a href="#" onclick="vibrate(); return false;">Vibrate</a></p>
```

When I leave out 'navigator.vibrate(time);' it does show the alert and if it stays in it doesn't show the alert so the line of 'navigator.vibrate(time);' causes a crash but only on ios. How can I fix this/ what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it’s [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Vibration_API#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: Run it on the ios device while inspecting the Web view console via Safari to Check for js errors. Otherwise the Error is thrown on the native Level and visible in xcode.

Comment: I just realised that phonegap probably opens the app in safari browser in ios and that isn't suporting the vibration plugin indeed @Xufox. Is there any other way I can let an safari webbrowser app vibrate?

Comment: just did some more testing and research, the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-vibration/#supported-platforms) sais that ios is suported. When I do 'alert(navigator.vibrate)' it sais: 'undefined'. Is it not suported then?